# How to console log member constructor DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
stream.on('tweet', tweet => {
    const twitterMessage = `${tweet.user.name} (@${tweet.user.screen_name}) have tweeted: https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name}/status/${tweet.id_str}`
    try {
       client.users.cache.each(user => {
           if(user.bot == false) {
             user.send(twitterMessage)
             console.log(user) 
           }
           
        })
        client.guild.members.cache.each(member => {
          console.log(member._roles)
        })
        
    }catch(e){
        console.log("[ERROR]", e)
    }
    
    return false;
  });
  
  
  client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is "ping"
  if (message.content === 'test') {
    // Send "pong" to the same channel
    message.guild.members.cache.each(member => {
      console.log(member._roles)
    })
  }
});
```

I am trying to get every user's role using discord. I have managed to get it to work when you use to send a message in a channel, however, I want to use it to verify someone's role and send them a message when someone tweets. The code above doesn't work and says member is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably coming from this line:

```js
client.guild.members.cache.each(member => {
```

`guild` is not a property of `client`. Instead, use `message.guild`, or `client.guilds.cache.get('<Guild ID>')`

Also, `_roles` is not a property of a `GuildMember` object. I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```js
if (member.roles.cache.has('<Role ID>') {
   // do something
};
```